# Search for a value in two columns in two different tables with SQL?

Tags: database, python-2.7, sqlite

I want a code to search for a value in two columns in two different SQL tables ,

```
a = raw_input('Enter name here') 
cur.execute('SELECT phone FROM participants')
b = cur.fetchall()
if a in b:
    print "The name is already exist"
```

Here I searched in on table (participants). What should I do to search in two tables?

Comment: What are "tow" tables?  What are "tow" columns?

Comment: if Tow is two, for tow table use SQL Join, and for Tow column use Where Clause

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are asking for SQL statement, you need to just use select from two tables instead of one. To keep everything in single statement, you can use UNION as described eg. here: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp

Let's assume you have second table, named friends with phone field also there.

Then, your SQL will be like this:

```
SELECT phone FROM participants where name = <input name here>
UNION
SELECT phone FROM friends where name = <input name here>
```

You can add sort at the end, if this is relevant for your case.
This you can also search more than one column in each table, by adding "or" clause, like this:

```
SELECT phone FROM participants where name = <your input here> or lastname = <your input here>
UNION
SELECT phone FROM friends where name = <your input here> or lastname = <your input here>
```

Of course, you have to replace  with proper search string. 
BTW, the code you provided is not searching anything - it is just dumping all phones from the table into "b" variable, which may be very inefficient especially when the table grows large. I strongly suggest to search via SQL and then present your output from script.